# Unable to figure output of socket programming program?

Tags: java, sockets

Maybe this question sounds like `very easy question`.But I am rookie in java.So that's why i want some clarity.

Here is my first class

```
public class Servertwo {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
     java.net.ServerSocket ss=new java.net.ServerSocket(4444);
     System.out.println("Wait for client");
     java.net.Socket cs=ss.accept();
     java.io.OutputStream os=cs.getOutputStream();
     DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(os);
     dos.writeUTF("Welcome to MyServer");
     dos.close();
     os.close();
     cs.close();
     ss.close();
 }
 }
```

Here is my second class

```
public class MyClienttwo {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    java.net.Socket cs=new java.net.Socket("127.0.0.1",4444);
    java.io.InputStream is=cs.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(is);
    String msg=dis.readUTF(dis);
    System.out.println(msg);
    dis.close();
    is.close();
    cs.close();
 }
 }
```

I am getting output as

> Welcome to MyServer

So here the server is printing `Welcome to MyServer` in outputStream.I just wanna know how the Client is able to read from OutputStream.

Comment: You do not read from an OutputStream, you read from an InputStream, which you are already doing. So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Steven i know it is reading from InputStream but I wanna know how data is transferred to inputstream

Comment: InputStream has a read() method and OutputStream has a write() method.  This is the essential difference between input and output.  Perhaps you are confusing this with a `Process` (which has the swapped around)

Comment: It is transferred using the Socket class and the OS via TCP.

Comment: @Peter I have just a simple question server is writing data into outputstream so how that data is transferred into inputstream?

Comment: @TruePS He's answered that, and so have I. TCP transfers it down the connection to the peer socket, from whence it becomes available via the peer's socket input stream, exactly as already expressed in your code. What part of that don't you understand?

Comment: @TruePS If you want to know this in depth, it is not a simple question.  You could write a book about how TCP really works. ;)

Comment: @all  So answer to my question is `The transfer of data through OutputStream to inputStream is happening through ` the Socket class and the OS via TCP.Am I right?

Comment: @TruePS As I am always right. ;) I would say so.

Comment: @TruePS It happens via the network and whatever the network comprises. Is this really such a mystery?

Comment: @Peter thanks for all your help I understood the concept.For deep understanding I will learn TCP

Comment: Can I recommend EJP's book on Network programming? ;)

Comment: @Peter Yeah sure BTW somebody downvoted my question.What SO has become.

Comment: What you need to comments on what you should do better to improve your question or answer, a hit-and-run down vote is worse than useless IMHO.

Comment: @Peter totally agree with you but I am the only one who was suffered here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just wanna know how the Client is able to read from OutputStream.

It isn't. It is reading from an `InputStream.`

If that doesn't answer your question, clarify it.

Comment: i know it is reading from InputStream but I wanna know how data is transferred to inputstream

Comment: By the socket. The writer writes to its `OutputStream,` which is connected to the socket, which transfers it down the connection, where it arrives at the peer socket, where it becomes available via the `InputStream.` It's all there in your own code.

Comment: @TruePS Are you talking about the wire format, Java classes used, the OS calls made, the transport protocol used, the details of how loopback works, how TCP works?

Comment: @EJP Wthat's what i am asking how 'where it arrives at the peer socket, where it becomes available via the InputStream.' this si happening because normally i read a say text file from a location and read that file into  inputstream

Comment: @TruePS I don't understand this new question, but I've answered your original question. If you want to know how sockets and TCP connections work, you're asking a much bigger question than anyone can answer here.

Comment: I am just asking how data becomes available at input Stream or How outputstream transfers data to inputstream here

Comment: Over TCP. Via the TCP transport layer, the network layer, the datalink layer, the physical layer, the network, TCP segments, IP packets, Ethernet, xDSL, packet-switching, electricity, electrons, particle physics, ... How much detail is going to satisfy you?

Comment: Plz don't get offended i am just a programmer just like you and asking for your help.I understood the concept now and accepted your answer but getting angry at somebody is not gonna help that person.

Comment: Nobody is offended, or angry. We just can't understand what you're talking about, or asking about, or why the concept of data over a network is so mysterious that it needs explanation. Or, for that matter, why more handwaving like 'over the network' is an acceptable answer. You can't blame other people for not understanding what it is that you don't understand. I still don't know.

Comment: But i thought your language suggest that you were angry(According to a new user).But thanks for your help and valuable time.